# Let $P$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ , $n \geq 2$, $P(X)=\prod_{i=1}^n \left(X-z_i \right)^{m_i}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

> Let $P$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ , $n \geq  2$.
>   $$P(X)=\prod_{i=1}^n  \left(X-z_i \right)^{m_i}$$ 
>    with zeros $z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n$
>
> - Decompose the rational fraction $\dfrac{P'}{P}$

My thoughts:

- $P(X)=\prod_{i=1}^n  \left(X-z_i \right)^{m_i}$
- $P'(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_i\left(X-z_i \right)^{m_i-1}\prod_{?}^{?}\left(X-z_i \right)^{m_?}$

I don't know with what i should fill the ?

Then:

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{P'}{P}&=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_i\left(X-z_i \right)^{m_i-1}\prod_{?}^{?}\left(X-z_i \right)^{m_i}}{\prod_{i=1}^n  \left(X-z_i \right)^{m_i}}  \\
&= ?
\end{align*}

I'm stuck here

Answer (score 1):

You can act as follows:$$P(X)=\prod_{i=1}^n  \left(X-z_i \right)^{m_i}\Rightarrow P'(X)=\sum_i^n m_i(X-z_i)^{m_i-1}\prod_{j\ne i}(X-z_j)^{m_j}=\sum_i^n m_i(X-z_i)^{m_i-1}\prod_{j\ne i}(X-z_j)^{m_j}\cdot\left( \frac{X-z_i}{X-z_i}\right)=\sum_i^n m_i(X-z_i)^{m_i-2}\prod_{i=1}^{n}(X-z_i)^{m_i}$$ Hence
$$\frac{P'(X)}{P(X)}=\sum_{i=1}^n m_i(X-z_i)^{m_i-2}$$

Comment: i can't see $\prod_{j\ne i}(X-z_j)^{m_j}$ from what to what could you elaborate please

Comment: It is an indirect answer to what you did not know when you put the signes "?". When you have taken the derivative,the indices of the product in each term with $m_i(X-z_i)^{m_i-1}$ must be all distinct of $i$.

Answer (score 0):

The product rule generalizes such that the result is the sum of things where each thing is a  derivative of one of the factors times the rest of the original products. For example $(fgh)' = f'gh+fg'h+fgh'$. So for your product, you want the product from $j=1$ to $i-1$ and then from $ j=i+1$ to $n$.

Comment: could you elaborate